# Access to the variables in the template from other component

Tags: angular

I need help with setting variables in the template from other components.

For example:

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: '/templates/layout',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink]
})

export class AppComponent {

    currentShop:Shop;

    constructor(router: Router, shopProvider:ShopProvider){
        shopProvider
            .getCurrentShop()
            .toPromise()
            .then((response) => {
                router.navigate(['/System']);
            });
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<app>
    <div>{{currentShop.name}}</div>
</app>
```

**Shop:**

```
export class Shop{

    private _id;

    private _name;

    constructor(id:number, name:string) {
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
    }

    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

**SystemComponent:**

```
@Component({
    template: '',
    directives: [RouterOutlet]
})

export class SystemComponent{

    private _routeParams:RouteParams;

    private _shopProvider:ShopProvider;

    currentShop:Shop;

    constructor(routeParams:RouteParams,shopProvider:ShopProvider){
        this._routeParams = routeParams;
        this.currentShop = new Shop(1, 'Test');
    }

}
```

After I run the application I get this error:

```
[Error] EXCEPTION: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'l_currentShop0.name') in [{{currentShop.name}} in AppComponent@22:12]
```

If I try to set up currentShop directly from the AppComponent, there is no problem. From SystemComponent it does not work.

Comment: Why do you display the current shop, which is an attribute of the System component, in the template of App? Display it in the template of System, where it belongs.

Comment: Because SystemComponent get currentShop via ShopProvider. This code is not complete.

Comment: You should expose a service for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the `ShopProvider` provides you the current asynchronously. If so, perhaps you try to display it whereas it's not there.

Perhaps the Elvis operator could help you:

```
{{currentShop?.name}}
```

Without any other hints (some ideas about how the `ShopProvider` service works and how you display the `currentShop` attribute in the view), it's difficult to help you more.

Thierry